# how i can make a select with cases counts with mysql

Tags: mysql

Good afternoon,

i have 3 tables on my mysql bank, like this picture:

[image: bank model]

i need to create a view with the user id (ok), name user (ok), quantity of this sells is installment and the quantity of this sells is in cash.

i have this code until now:

```
Select 
     user.id,
     user.name
FROM user
     JOIN sells ON user.id = sells.id_user
     JOIN installment ON installment.id_sell = sells.id
GROUP BY user.id
```

Comment: you forgot to mention what the problem is

Comment: `SELECT u.id, u.name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sells WHERE id_user = u.id), ... FROM user u`, maybe